# Create surface from LiDAR and shapefile extents

Tags: qgis, shapefile, tin, surface

I am trying to create a TIN surface from LiDAR points and the extents of a shapefile, so that the whole shapefile is filled with a surface based on the available point data. If I create a TIN surface with the points now, it only creates a surface to the extent of the points.

Any ideas?

[image: QGIS]

Comment: Of course its just in the extent of the Point Layer! You cant interpolate without Data. Why you want to interpolate outside your Data Points? You wont get usefull values in this area...
If you really want, you could add manually Points and assign values to it. But then you still will just get "real" values inside the original Points, because you simulate the new Points without knowing the real Value.

Comment: Add a DEM for that area?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Well, I want to create a 3D model of a city, so I am going to make surfaces from different objects (roads, green etc) and then extract solids from them. These are all based on shapefile extents, so to fit them correctly it would be best to interpolate them to that extent automatically. For this example (water), there is a extremely little amount of points, for others this is not the case.

Comment: The altitude of water should not change much, if there is no barier like a floodgate, right?. So in this case you could add manually Points at the borders of your Polygon. Or you just use the Tool native:createconstantrasterlayer.